# deploy a war into EC2 using cloudfoundry console

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-foundry

I have been trying hard to deploy a java application through cloudfoundry into an Amazon EC2 instance using the console as described in this screencast video on cloud foundry.
http://classic.cloudfoundry.com/screencasts.html
but only failing to get the console where I can deploy by choosing a war from the local file system, as explained in the video..

What is the correct URL where I can find a console similar to the one shown in the video ??
And I have already tried signing up for the url http://classis.cloudfoundry.com, but not getting an approval or acknowledgement mail from the team even after 4 days..

Did anyone face similar issue in the recent times?
If yes please help!

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Foundry Classic service (at http://classic.cloudfoundry.com) is no longer accepting new accounts.